# How can I handle a notification from Firebase when it arrives and I have the app open?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to update activities when a notification arrives but I can't get the current Activity where the user is.
I'm working with FirebaseMessagingService.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB0en.png)

Comment: "I can't get the current Activity where the user is" Why not? What is keeping you from doing this?

Comment: How can I get the current activity? Maybe i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: That could be. The best chance you have of getting help, is to show us what you tried already. Without that it is unlikely we'll do better than the top results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+get+the+current+android+activity%3F

Comment: I just uploaded an image of the code. Thanks!!!

Comment: You should always add code in the editor using markdown and not as an image, it becomes easier for people to edit if they have to

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. That allows it to be searched, and allows us to copy/paste it to reproduce the issue, or in our answers.

Comment: After that, can you explain what isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message? It might also help to spend a moment to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and following the guidance in there gives you the best chance that someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that when receiving the notification the application may be in the foreground or background and that depending on it the handling is different.

You cannot get the activity from that service, instead, you have to tell it which activity appears in the foreground when the notification is clicked and get the "extras" data.

For example using a configuration like this in the notification server (nodejs):

```
var message = {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: text
        },
        data: {
            title: title,
            body: text,
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            name: name
        },
        android: {
            priority: 'high',
            notification: {
                sound: 'default',
                clickAction: '.PetNotificationActivity'
            },
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    sound: 'default'
                },
            },
        },
        tokens: registrationTokens
    };
```

In that example, **PetNotificationActivity** is the activity that I want to bring to the foreground when opening the notification.

And, In the **PetNotificationActivity** something like this (**for background/closed app case**):

```
public class PetNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pet_notification);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            String latitudeValue = bundle.getString("latitude");
            String longitudeValue = bundle.getString("longitude");
            String nameValue = bundle.getString("name");
            ...
        }
    }
```

And in the service something like this (**for foreground case**):

```
public class PetNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String messageBody = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String latitude = remoteMessage.getData().get("latitude");
        String longitude = remoteMessage.getData().get("longitude");
        String name = remoteMessage.getData().get("name");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PetNotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        ...

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        ...
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

FCM documentation at [Handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be for your interested activities to register a broadcast receiver and for your service to send a broadcast when a message arrives.